# System arguments error in python

Tags: python, sys

I have recently started using sys.argv in python and I am trying the following thing:

```
import sys
[filename]=sys.argv[0:1]
[NumoflinesToread]=sys.argv[1:2]
[tmax]=sys.argv[2:3]
```

This takes the first three arguments after the script. I want to add an error message which states what arguments a user should provide and what it means. Something like the following:

> Script Aborted: Following arguments required:
>   1. Input Filename
>   2. Max. Lines to be read
>   3. Max. time step.

Comment: Why are you using slices? Why not just `filename = sys.argv[0]`?

Comment: Note also that `sys.argv[0]` is the name of the script, the first argument is in `sys.argv[1]`.

Comment: Use `len(sys.argv)` to find out how many arguments they supplied. If they didn't supply enough, print the error message.

Comment: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​Well, you can just check the length of `sys.argv` use `len(sys.argv)`. And if it's not `=> 3`, then `raise SystemExit('Script Aborted: Following arguments required: 1. Input Filename 2. Max. Lines to be read 3. Max. time step.')`. And I'd also suggest you take a look at [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/argparse.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `len(sys.argv)` to check and give the message of course. But a more pythonic way to do this is using `try` block

```
import sys
try 
    filename=sys.argv[0]
    NumoflinesToread=sys.argv[1]
    tmax=sys.argv[2]
except IndexError:
    print Your_error_message
```

Finally, I would suggest you to use a more comprehensive module like [optparse](https://docs.python.org/2/library/optparse.html) or [Click](http://click.pocoo.org/5/).